# How to create EC2 AMI images with multiple nitro-based volumes attached correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm using the EC2 image builder to automate the process of creating AMI images for mongoDB servers.

This image has two volumes:

- `/data` - 100 GB
- `/logs` - 10 GB

To achieve this setup I've created an [image builder recipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/imagebuilder/latest/userguide/manage-recipes.html) with 3 volumes attached (one is for the root `/`).

Then, an image builder component formats and mounts the volumes. Here is the snippet of the steps doing this:

```
  - name: FormatAndMountDataVolume
    action: ExecuteBash
    inputs:
      commands:
        - sudo mkdir /data
        - sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
        - echo "/dev/nvme1n1  /data  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
        - sudo mount -a
        - sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data
  - name: FormatAndMountLogsVolume
    action: ExecuteBash
    inputs:
      commands:
        - sudo mkdir /logs
        - sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1
        - echo "/dev/nvme2n1  /logs  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
        - sudo mount -a
        - sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /logs
```

It works fine and the image is created. The issue is that the instances use the Nitro-System and their documentation states the following:

> The device names are /dev/nvme0n1, /dev/nvme1n1, and so on. The device names that you specify in a block device mapping are renamed using NVMe device names (/dev/nvme[0-26]n1). **The block device driver can assign NVMe device names in a different order than you specified for the volumes in the block device mapping.**

So, there a potential issue with the AMI above. It mounts the directory `/data` on the device `/dev/nvme1n1` and the `/logs` on `/dev/nvme2n1`, but Amazon does not guarantee that the devices will be named using this order. The instance might end up having a `/logs` folder with 100GB capacity while the `/data` has only 10GB.

Any idea on how to make sure the volumes will be mounted on the correct folders when running EC2 instances for this AMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your script you have one step that creates the file system with `mkfs` and another step to add it on `fstab` file.

Before add it on `fstab` get the `UUID` from device you just formatted.
Use this `UUID` to add mount instructions to `fstab`, instead of device path.

This is how you can change your code.

```
  commands:
    - sudo mkdir /data
    - sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
    - echo "$(blkid /dev/nvme1n1 | awk '{print $2}')  /data  xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

See this other answer about UUID usage:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568780/aws-nvme-mounted-to-different-directory-after-reboot/67453438?noredirect=1#comment119235037_67453438

---

**Update**

Your concept about AMI and when volumes are related to it is not correct.
Volumes are attached exactly when you generate AMI, doesn't matter which mechanism you use to generate it.
When you generated your AMI using image builder, it will attach volumes on it and will run the commands you added to format your device (see note). Exactly at the moment you create AMI. Not when you create instance.
So, filesystem is already there with `UUID`, `fstab` is already configured.

Every instance you create later from this AMI, will be exactly the same as this AMI.

See this example, I create one instance, formatted device with `xfs`, mounted it via `fstab`, stopped it and generated an AMI.
Then I launched a new instance from this AMI, see that all devices `UUID` are the same, even the one from root volume.

Before generate AMI, instance name `ip-172-31-12-219`:

```
[root@ip-172-31-12-219 ~]# lsblk -f
NAME          FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1
└─nvme1n1p1   xfs          e24884d7-26a2-457d-bf51-875907986bf0 /mnt/disk10
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1   xfs    /     7b355c6b-f82b-4810-94b9-4f3af651f629 /
└─nvme0n1p128
```

Another instance from AMI above, instance name `ip-172-31-8-239`:

```
[root@ip-172-31-8-239 ~]# lsblk -f
NAME          FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1
└─nvme1n1p1   xfs          e24884d7-26a2-457d-bf51-875907986bf0 /mnt/disk10
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1   xfs    /     7b355c6b-f82b-4810-94b9-4f3af651f629 /
└─nvme0n1p128
```

When you generate AMI from console you can see this message.

> During the image creation process, Amazon EC2 creates a snapshot of each of the above volumes.

Which means when you create an instance from this AMI, all volumes are a "restore" from these snapshots. Every bit and byte are the same.

I hope I have clarified your doubts here.

---

**Note**

Totally out of topic, you are creating a filesystem on your disk instead of a partition. It is okay, it is supported. But it is not recommended.
You can search more about each option. One advantage is partition alignment, which is very helpful with SSD.

Comment: Hi @Azize, I've seen your answer and that solution works perfectly when you're working on a instance. My issue here is that I'm building an image and there's no way to know the UUID of the volumes at this point since they will be attached only at launch time.

Comment: thank you for you detailed answer. I assumed that the volumes attached to new instances would have a different UUID.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the labels instead.

1. It is more user readable
2. It works even if device names gets changed.

Here is an example:

```
- name: FormatAndMountDataVolume
  action: ExecuteBash
  inputs:
    commands:
      - sudo mkdir /data
      - sudo mkfs -t xfs -L DATA /dev/xvdb
      - echo "LABEL=DATA  /data xfs  defaults,nofail  0  2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
      - sudo mount /data
```